# Wie kann man "line-map" in diesem Kontext ins Deutsche übersetzen?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

Ich möchte eine Frage über die Deutsche Frage stellen. Und zwar lese ich gerade [diese Antwort auf math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1938935) und da steht:

> For addition, think of it like a line-map, and you are taking directions. It doesn't matter if you stop at a, sleep, and then go further b+c, versus stopping at a+b, sleep, then go further c. You'll end up at the same place, no matter what.

Ich interessiere mich dafür, wie man das Wort "line-map" ins Deutsche übersetzen kann. Schaut man im Internet nach, so stößt man auf die Übersetzung "Linienplan" (etwa von einer Busstrecke, Metro, Straßenbahn, …). Dieses Wort passt aber vom Kontext her nicht. Deswegen meine Frage: Wie kann man das Wort "line-map" in diesem Kontext geeignet *ins Deutsche* übersetzen? Vielleicht einfach mit nur "Linie" oder "Pfeil"?

Wenn ihr meine Frage über die deutsche Sprache beantworten könntet, dann wäre ich euch sehr dankbar.

Comment: Und warum passt "Linienplan" nicht?

Comment: Um zu wissen, ob „Linienplan“ passt, müssten wir wissen, was der Autor der Antwort meinte. Das kann nur er beantworten.

Comment: Wenn Deine Frage geschlossen wurde, stelle sie bitte nicht einfach erneut, sondern versuche die Probleme der geschlossenen Frage zu beheben. Wenn Dir das nicht gelingt oder nicht zu einer Wiedereröffnung führt, kannst Du das Ganze auf [meta] diskutieren. In Deinem Fall sieht es aber danach aus, dass Du einen englischen Begriff verstehen möchtest und deswegen hier an der komplett falschen Stelle bist. Wenn ich mich irre und Du den englischen Begriff verstanden hast, dann erläutere bitte, was er bedeutet – was genau das ist, was m. E. zur Wiedereröffnung der anderen Frage fehlt.

Answer (score -2):

In dem Beispiel ist von einer Reise mit Übernachtungen die Rede. Der Kontext im Sinne der von Bus, Bahn oder Metro ist also in Ordnung.

Treffender wäre aber vielleicht "Reiseplan".

Comment: Gesucht ist aber das Wort für den mathematischen Kontext.